# get application version in windows application c#

Tags: c#, version

I use this code for get application version

```
private string CurrentVersion
    {
        get
        {
            return ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed
                   ? ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString()
                   : Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        }
    }
```

But in debug mode and when I publish and install application I get 1.0.0.0.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you set the version? (Goto Project-properties-publish !)

Comment: yes , i set version in project propertices - > publish -> publish version

Comment: @developerweb Have you set it in `Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information`?

Comment: Is 'Increment when publishing'`checked?

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev , oh , i don't set this file,its necessary?because i always work whit publish section in project propertices

Comment: @TaW yes,Increment is checked

Comment: @developerweb Of course, yes. You try to get `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version` but you haven't set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code you are actually trying to obtain an assembly version.

```
return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

You need to set the assembly version in `Properties -> Application -> Assembly Information`.